# axios function is running after other lines of code

Tags: javascript, axios, request, geocoding

My Code:

```js
var latlng = {lat: 7, lng: 7};

function findLatLng() {
    var testLocation = '350 Victoria St, Toronto';

    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
            address: testLocation,
            key: 'MY KEY',
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location);
        return response.data.results[0].geometry.location;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

latlng = findLatLng();
console.log(latlng);
```

In the console, `latlng` is logged as undefined, but the `console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location)` is logged with the proper value;
it is also logged afterwards even though it should have executed first.

I think this is because the code continues despite `findLatLng()` not being done with the request but I'm not sure.
When I check the value of `latlng` in the console afterwards, it becomes the proper value.

What is the issue and how do I fix this please?

Comment: `latlng = findLatLng();` doesn’t make sense. `findLatLng` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: return response.data.results[0].geometry.location; also doesn't make sense here.
try to update latlng in success/error cases